# How and where to create one function to sign out which is accessible to all activities in android?

Tags: android, events, android-activity

I have so many activities in my android app, most of them have sign out button, I want to create only function which can be accessed through multiple activities in android. Do I have to add a function in Application Class?

Below images will help you understand the scenario

http://cubixshade.com/images/1.jpg

http://cubixshade.com/images/2.jpg

http://cubixshade.com/images/3.jpg

Sign out button and functionality will be same in all activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an abstract activity subclass.

```
public abstract YourActivityWithSignOut extends Activity
```

Implement only the needed functionality and UI in this class, and then have all your other activities extend YouActivityWithSignOut instead of android.app.Activity.

Comment: +1 I like this approach (obviously there are others that work as well) because it means that you can put common code that is associated with activity-type workflow there. I use this approach as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Application class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) for Creating fields or methods which you want to share  between all Components of an Application. 

if you create sign out method in Application class then you will access it in all Activities

you can see this tutorial for how we use Application class for sharing common method's or fields between Activities

http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/